# Are there facilities for luggage storage in Barranquilla?

Tags: luggage-storage, barranquilla

While staying a few days in Barranquilla, I plan to head out of town to nature for a few days and would like to leave some luggage in town. I am also *not* leaving via the airport, so I would prefer a location in the city somewhere.

Where can I safely leave a single suitcase or backpack for a few days in the town of Barranquilla, Colombia?

Comment: I wont post this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure, but luggage storage is not common in Colombia. I'm Colombian so I've never had the need for one, but I've never seen one either.

Comment: Couldn't find any, there was a storage location in Cartagena bus terminal but not in Barranquilla. That doesn't mean there isn't any, just not where I looked.

Comment: Hotels are quite cheap there: what about booking one to get the option to store your luggage? Also, the airport may have lockers.

Comment: @pnuts - Unfortunately no. I realize its hard to prove there isn't but it certainly is not at any of the two bus terminals I used. Didn't check the airport though as it was not on my path.

Comment: @pnuts - Ended up carrying all my stuff and getting a better workout than expected ;) The hotel *probably* could have stored the luggage but there was so many people coming in and out, as it was carnaval, staff changes, that I didn't want to risk it.

Comment: @DGaleano could you gather more information on this topic? Many bounties are being started to clarify it!

Comment: fedorqui unfortunately no. I'm not from that region and my only source at this point would be internet and @markmayo could do it himself. As I said before I don't think there is one storage easy to find but I like your idea about a hotel. Mark if during your research you find a site in spanish that you don't fully understand send me a link at diego.galeano at gmail and I'll try to help.

Comment: @fedorqui unfortunately no. I'm not from that region and my only source at this point would be internet and markmayo could do it himself. In this subject I can only offer to help in the way I express on my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the Barranquilla bus terminal or the airport have any luggage storage facilities (or at least none are listed on their websites), so your best bet is to book a hotel room for a few days and drop off your things there. [Booking.com](http://www.booking.com/searchresults.en-gb.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaDqIAQGYAS64AQbIAQzYAQPoAQGoAgM&sid=26222a38d375e8366dfcd41ea62b929d&checkin_month=11&checkin_monthday=9&checkin_year=2016&checkout_month=11&checkout_monthday=10&checkout_year=2016&class_interval=1&dest_id=-578007&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&group_adults=2&group_children=0&hlrd=0&hyb_red=0&inac=0&label_click=undef&nha_red=0&no_rooms=1&postcard=0&redirected_from_city=0&redirected_from_landmark=0&redirected_from_region=0&review_score_group=empty&room1=A%2CA&sb_price_type=total&score_min=0&src_elem=sb&ss=Barranquilla%2C%20Atl%C3%A1ntico%2C%20Colombia&ss_all=0&ss_raw=barr&ssb=empty&sshis=0&order=price) lists a few acceptable options for as little as 20 EUR per day, which is possibly acceptable for many travelers.

[image]